# Почему не удаётся запустить Telegram-клиент на Pyrogram?

Tags: python, pyrogram

Использую Pyrogram версии 2.0.102. Код программы - стандартный, взятый из официальной документации.

```py
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client

api_id = 12345
api_hash = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"

async def main():
    async with Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash) as app:
        await app.send_message("me", "Greetings from **Pyrogram**!")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Traceback ошибки:

```
File "pyrogram\client.py", line 311, in __aenter__
File "pyrogram\methods\utilities\start.py", line 58, in start
File "pyrogram\methods\auth\connect.py", line 40, in connect
File "pyrogram\client.py", line 637, in load_session
File "pyrogram\session\auth.py", line 274, in create
File "pyrogram\session\auth.py", line 89, in create
File "pyrogram\session\auth.py", line 67, in invoke
File "pyrogram\session\auth.py", line 60, in unpack
File "pyrogram\raw\core\tl_object.py", line 33, in read
KeyError: 0
[2016] Failed to execute script 'collector' due to unhandled exception!
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы до конца авторизованы? Без асинхронного запуска работает? Попробуйте обновить библиотеку и добавить phone_number='89992223344' в Client если вы авторизуетесь как пользователь.

```
Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash, phone_number='you_phone_number')
```